# "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" when archiving

Tags: react-native, expo, xcode11

so I have an app built with Expo but then ejected to get ios and android folder everything works fine on both android and ios I have published it for android but on ios when I try to archive the project it gives me an error `Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with nonzero exit code` i don't know what's causing this error I have read a lot of StackOverflow questions tried a lot of things but with no luck here's what I tried so far.

I tried:

- removing pod lock file, removing pod folder, doing `pod deintegrate`,
  doing `pod update`

  - locking and unlocking the login in keychainAccess
  - cleaning build folder in xcode
  - restarting my laptop and xcode
  - changing to legacy build system from new build system
  - removing DerivedData folder and cleaning Xcode
- upgrading cocopods and doing pod install again

Okay so before, building with `Command+B` also didn't work but now i went to Targets->App name->build phases->bundle expo assets-> and checked the " run script only while installing" option and building started working but archiving still doesn't work

along with the above error i also noticed another error on xcode

[image]

So please if anyone has any ideas why this is happening, please?

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

it is due to [Bare Expo Bundle Assets](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/7986)

here is the actual issue raised on forum: 
https://forums.expo.io/t/ios-bundle-assets-error-when-building-release-403/36616

this [pull](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/pull/1999) (fix) request has merged into master

-

[**Solution:**](https://forums.expo.io/t/ios-bundle-assets-error-when-building-release-403/36616/10)

**update your expo-cli to expo-cli@3.19.2 or higher**

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

-

### **Note: Solution 1 is the answer to this question**

**Solution 2:**

Open project directory on the terminal and run this command and archive again

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle
```

**Solution 3:**

Go to

`Keychain Access` -> `Right-click on login` -> `Lock & unlock again`
-> `Clean Xcode project` ->`Make build again`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215713/discussion-on-answer-by-muhammad-numan-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with).

Comment: I'm already on expo-cli version 4.4.8, so solution 1 does't work for me

Comment: This is no longer the solution. You should not be using global expo-cli

Answer (score 72):

One possible reason could be that Xcode is using an outdated version of Node (in my case, it was because I use nvm to manage my Node versions, but Xcode used an old version of Node that I had installed via HomeBrew a long time ago).

By default, Xcode will use the Node binary located at `/usr/local/bin/node`. Check its version by running:

```sh
/usr/local/bin/node -v
node -v
```

If the first command outputs an older version of Node, simply delete it and replace it with a symlink to the newer one:

```sh
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node
ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node
```

Comment: This fixed it for me!

Comment: Busy updating a RN project from 0.62.3 to 0.67.1, also am running nvm for node version manager.  This solved my last remaining problem.  Project now builds!

Comment: I had never installed node separately (or maybe I have removed that one at some point). So there was nothing at `/usr/local/bin/node`. But this command fixed the issue for me `ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node`. Thank you

Comment: genuinely nothing worked till this. thanks! iOS16 with xcode 14 & react native 0.70.1.

Comment: is this effect for current working projects?

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the time wasting issue.

Comment: amazing! Worked out!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was pulling my hair with this issue. In my case, I had to add `sudo` to create the symlink.

Comment: worked on M1 AIR

Comment: Google brings me back this answer every year, and every year it saves me. I wish I could upvote it more than once. Or get a better memory.

Comment: Thanks,
Worked for me In
Xcode 15.3
and Mac OS-14.3.1

Answer (score 10):

If you are using nvm, unsetting the default alias fixes the issue.

```
$ nvm unalias default
```

or if it asking to set nvm default:

```
$ nvm alias default node
```

Build the app again.

Comment: this worked for me  (in addition to setting the link )  thanks.

Comment: You saved my head, man. I've been on this for over a week. I owe you a drink!!!

Answer (score 7):

My actual Error came from just above the PhaseScriptExecution part, it was due to `Error: cannot find the node binary. Try setting the NODE_BINARY variable in the...`

When Xcode looks for Node at `/usr/local/bin/node` it's not literally there, since nvm uses a more specific, dynamic path.

The solution is simple. Setup a system link based on your node path. Then try your build again. Run this in the terminal:

```
ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node
```

This answer comes from this SO answer: [React Native ios build : Can't find node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492197/react-native-ios-build-cant-find-node#answer-50419734)
But is also mentioned in other answers there, and comments.
This is also similar to @ashwin-m answer, but I found I didn't understand that one.

Answer (score 2):

unsetting the default alias fixed my issue.

```
$ nvm unalias default
```

clean the build folder then rebuild the project.

note : I'm using Xcode 14.0.1

Answer (score 1):

This issue for me was that I had the project in a directory with spaces in the name. An intermediate script that FBReactNativeSpec builds is referencing paths without escaping spaces, so it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Build the project with Xcode, you can see more details with the error if you scroll up. In my case it was a problem with the JS code, and not a problem natively. See my image below. JS error up top, and PhaseScriptExecution error below.

[image: Error: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code]

If you are running from Xcode instead of react-native command line, you'll have to clean the build folder in Xcode before trying again.

Answer (score 1):

As per a PR comment here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/42221#issuecomment-1895955415, I needed to delete my local file `.xcode.env.local` and then `pod install` to resolve this; after updating the node versions as explained in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as John said when I try to init a new RN project. But turns out I had to recreate the project in the path without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this for others who may stumble across this post in search of a solution.

I tried just about every possible solution for this error and none seemed to work. In my case, it ended up being that I was using a monorepo.

If you're also using RN inside of a monorepo, a possible solution may be ensure that your RN modules are not being hoisted. RN seems to rely heavily on `node_modules` existing at the same level as the project; which clashes with monorepo hoisting.

If you're using Yarn, you can add the following to your package.json (the child repo where RN is used)

```
"workspaces": {
  "nohoist": [
    "**/*",
  ]
},
```

You can also exclude individual packages from being hoisted if you don't want to exclude everything, but I found that I still kept getting some variation of error until I excluded everything. With more trial and error, it's possible you don't have to exclude everything.

Answer (score 0):

In order to **fix this issue on my M1 Mac**,

I had to delete all lines containing `EXCLUDED_ARCHS = arm64;`
in this file `ios/YOUR_APP_NAME.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue in 2023, please be sure to have checked the log file with the complete report.

I've found just before the "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" message in the report, the real problem was there.

Log files are located in the next path on macOS:
/Users/your.name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/yourprojectname-hcgvgedvowxgnneoecsorwuhwmtq/Logs/Build

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience with this error. There might be different solution that'll work for you as pretty much all the most voted ones actually do solve it depending on the problem you actually have going on.

I had NVM installed using Homebrew. I did hard code node path for NODE_BINARY in xcode.env and xcode.local.env but I still kept getting the error (something like that)

```
hermes engine Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

**Solution**: I removed flipper and it started running successfully. I had checked everything and tried other solutions but nothing else worked in my case. I ran the following command in my project directory.

```
NO_FLIPPER=1 bundle exec pod install --project-directory=ios
```

Other Tips:

1. Make sure your whole path leading upto the directory has no spaces and special characters.
2. If you are using NVM, then you can hard code node paths using "which node" command and set these paths in ios/.xcode.env and
   ios/.xcode.local.env file
3. If you are using apple silicon, then go to node_modules/react-native/scripts/find-node-for-xcode.sh and add
   make adjustments in it like mentioned in other answers like
   hardcoding node path into PATH variable and commenting out that
   HOMEBREW_M1_BIN stuff.

Below is the result of my setup "npx react-native info"

```
System:
  OS: macOS 14.1.1
  CPU: (11) arm64 Apple M3 Pro
  Memory: 67.06 MB / 18.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 18.19.0
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.0/bin/node
  Yarn:
    version: 1.22.21
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
  npm:
    version: 10.2.3
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.0/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2023.12.04.00
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.14.3
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 23.2
      - iOS 17.2
      - macOS 14.2
      - tvOS 17.2
      - watchOS 10.2
  Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: Not Found
  Xcode:
    version: 15.1/15C65
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java: Not Found
  Ruby:
    version: 2.6.10
    path: /usr/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.73.0
    wanted: 0.73.0
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the “Podfile.lock file” using the command “rm -rf
   Podfile.lock” in the terminal.
2. Execute the command ‘rm -rf Pods’ in the terminal to remove the
   entire Pods folder.
3. Locate the “.xcworkspace” file in your project directory and delete
   it. Run the “pod install” command.
4. Clean the build folder by going to “Product > Clean Build Folder” to
   clear any previous build artifacts and start with a clean build.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your project folder name
if your project name is existing black space so you face error i have resolve it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Like Santiago's answer, I was running from a monorepo. However, the "nohoist" didn't work for me. Instead the issue had to do with the permissions of my project.

What helped me was changing the permissions of the root of the project. I did this by navigating to the parent directory of the project, then running

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ./ProjectName
```

That seemed to solve the issue for me.