# How can I fix error when building React-Native 0.68.0?

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, podspec, react-native-0.68.2

The issue seems to be known on the React-Native github repo, but I'm not able to find a solution.

Building a new project on version **0.68.0** always fails with :

[image]

I tried many solutions found here and there.

Here are the most obvious troubleshooting steps I took :

- Restarted computer
- Deleted Podfile.lock
- Updated pods
- Removed everything related to Xcode and re-installed Xcode

My colleague and I both use a MBP. Everything works fine for him since he's able to build >= **0.68.0** projects.

Here's my configuration :
[image]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ NOT BUILDING

Here's his configuration :
[image]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ BUILDING

Any hint ?

EDIT : Created a 0.69.0-rc.6 project and it builds properly.

Comment: Check this solution: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66497247/13632102)

Comment: Thx @HarshPatel. I tried the different solutions provided in the post but none solved the issue . Plus, everything is up to date regrading Node.

Comment: The React Native versions are different - 0.68.0 not building, 0.68.2 building. Have you tried matching those versions?

Comment: Yes, it just because we tried to start a project for every version from 0.68.0. For every versions the issue is the same , I'm not able to build but my teammate can.

Answer (score 0):

try deleting files in the following:

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

then clean build folder and rebuild

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did it many times already.

Comment: have you deleted your pods folder and .xcworkspace file and ran pod install again?