# How should I proceed to know exactly where a React-Native phase building script throws an error?

Tags: xcode, bash, react-native, shell

I'm bad with Xcode.

Based on this error :

[image]

How should I proceed to know exactly where the script throws an error ?

I tried to echo some things from different files found in node_modules since I'm troubleshooting an issue, but it does not appear anywhere.

What steps should I take to troubleshoot properly ?

see my related issue : [How can I fix error when building React-Native 0.68.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72697387/how-can-i-fix-error-when-building-react-native-0-68-0?noredirect=1#comment128412441_72697387)

Comment: Look for if you mistakenly imported a library that doesn't exist, or maybe you uninstalled any npm package and forgot to remove the import statement or code snippet. Further more do these steps, `npm run clean` then `npx react-native start --reset-cache` then run the project, it might give you exact line of code where the issue is..

Comment: As I mentioned in the related issue, I'm trying to build a brand new project. So I did not code or import anything.

Comment: Okay, but you haven't mentioned it as a new project, the error is not related to XCode, the problem lies in ReactNative code, if your project contain `build` folder try remove it, if not, try run on Android.