# react-native "Segmentation fault: 11 bash -l -c ..." when build app

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

## What I want to achieve

At react-native
`yarn run:ios`
When I try to launch an existing app, an error occurs and it doesn't work.

## premise

The execution environment is as follows.

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.6
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
    Memory: 179.06 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.20.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.nodebrew/current/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.19.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.09.18.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.12.1 - /Users/teraichi/.rbenv/shims/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2022.3 AI-223.8836.35.2231.10671973
    Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: javac 21 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    react-native: 0.64.4 => 0.64.4 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

## Problems/error messages occurring

Below is an excerpt of the error message that occurs when building from xCode.

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs 
/Users/teraichi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cucom-
basegvsyhmpmsgdvjavywleoezbw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-
iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-9666B301DB9D9BA74C1C0CDD9B765E7B.sh 
(in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')

...

/Users/teraichi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cucom-
basegvsyhmpmsgdvjavywleoezbw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-
iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-9666B301DB9D9BA74C1C0CDD9B765E7B.sh: 
line 4: 23095 Segmentation fault: 11  bash -l -c 'SRCS_DIR=/Users/teraichi/Work/Cucom-App-
v2/node_modules/react-native/scripts/../Libraries 
CODEGEN_MODULES_OUTPUT_DIR=/Users/teraichi/Work/Cucom-App-v2/node_modules/react-
native/scripts/../React/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec CODEGEN_MODULES_LIBRARY_NAME=
FBReactNativeSpec /Users/teraichi/Work/Cucom-App-
v2/node_modules/react-native/scripts/generate-specs.sh' 2>&1
     23096 Done                    | tee "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}"
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Even if I build from xCode or from yarn, I get the same error.

## Applicable source code

```
# /Users/teraichi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cucom-basegvsyhmpmsgdvjavywleoezbw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-9666B301DB9D9BA74C1C0CDD9B765E7B.sh

#!/bin/sh
set -o pipefail

bash -l -c 'SRCS_DIR=/Users/teraichi/Work/Cucom-App-v2/node_modules/react-native/scripts/../Libraries CODEGEN_MODULES_OUTPUT_DIR=/Users/teraichi/Work/Cucom-App-v2/node_modules/react-native/scripts/../React/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec CODEGEN_MODULES_LIBRARY_NAME=FBReactNativeSpec /Users/teraichi/Work/Cucom-App-v2/node_modules/react-native/scripts/generate-specs.sh' 2>&1 | tee "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}"
```

## What I tried

- Restart my computer
- OS version up
- update xCode version
- node version up、version down
- Other solutions posted on the internet

## Sites referred to

["Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" when archiving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62245176/command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code-when-archiving/74007424#74007424)

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34269

Answer (score 0):

1. First, try cleaning the build folder by selecting Product > Clean Build Folder in Xcode and then try building again.
2. It's possible that the Node modules may not have been installed correctly, so try reinstalling the modules by running the following commands in the project directory:

   ```
   rm -rf node_modules
   npm install // or yarn install
   ```
3. There might be an issue with the CocoaPods installation, so try reinstalling the pods by running the following commands in the iOS project directory:

   ```
   cd ios
   rm -rf Podfile.lock Pods
   pod install
   ```