# What's the proper way to use patch-package for iOS circleci builds

Tags: react-native, circleci, fastlane, nvm, patch-package

During a react-native upgrade from version 0.63 to 0.65.2 I ran [into an issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31249#issuecomment-811715288) where `react-native/scripts/find-node.sh` was failing on my CircleCI builds. Turns out this is nvm/node related as discussed in the link above. I was able to verify this by ssh'ing on to a circle build, updating the node_modules/react-native/scripts/find-node.sh with the suggested fix of adding `unset PREFIX` to the top of the file and running the build again. It was successful. [A related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66627590/phasescriptexecution-error-in-react-native-app) about this issue suggested using `patch-package` to apply this fix.

However, our circle builds use fastlane and fails on the `ensure_git_status_clean` step because of the suggested method in `patch-package`'s [circleci section](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package#circleci). This method is basically creating a new file that causes the git status to be unclean.

So my question is, what is the best way to handle this without creating a new `patches.hash` file or how can it be created in a way that keeps the git status clean during the fastlane step of the cirleci build?