# Xcodebuild Archive Failed with error PhaseScriptExecution Jenkins

Tags: ios, jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

I am trying to create iOS archive from jenkins. Whereas the Build PC the Build Command is working fine but when I run from jenkins the same command I get this issue. This is a React Native Project

COMMAND:

```
sh 'xcrun xcodebuild archive -workspace AppName.xcworkspace -scheme Test -sdk iphoneos -configuration release -allowProvisioningUpdates -destination "generic/platform=iOS" arch=x86_64  -archivePath "/Users/ali/Desktop/Test_bulds"'
```

ERROR:

```
    /Users/ali/jenkins/workspace/Mobile/MobileAppBuild/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'react-native-blur' from project 'Pods')
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/ali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname-hamnkyelypjutaefdzwfxmvlwith/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Test/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Appname.build/Release-iphoneos/Appname.build/Script-CF1348D5D60844C3DD63C481.sh (in target 'AppName' from project 'AppNAme')
```

Comment: The Jenkins Mac probably is missing or has missconfigured some command line tool. Check the detailed log, this is the xcactivitylog file in Logs/Build, rename it to .gzip and unzip it. Also check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66627590/phasescriptexecution-error-in-react-native-app.

Answer (score 0):

You mostly need to change this line in your podfile to a higher version:

```
#Change this to something like '12'
platform :ios, '12'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}
```