# error: Can't find the 'node' binary to build the React Native bundle

Tags: node.js, xcode, npm, npm-start, metro-bundler

I am trying to run an app from Xcode and am running into this error:

`error: Can't find the 'node' binary to build the React Native bundle.  If you have a non-standard Node.js installation, select your project in Xcode, find  'Build Phases' - 'Bundle React Native code and images' and change NODE_BINARY to an  absolute path to your node executable. You can find it by invoking 'which node' in the terminal.`

My node version:

- v18.0.0

NPM version:

- 8.6.0

The metro bundler seems to be getting caught on something. I updated my Xcode path to be the absolute path of my node executable.

I updated my bash profile to have the node export as well:

`export NODE_BINARY=/Users/oliviaporter/.nvm/versions/node/v18.0.0/bin/node`

what else do I need to do to get Xcode to see the node path?

[image]

Comment: Hi Please find a solution in following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492197/react-native-ios-build-cant-find-node

Comment: I also faced a similar issue due to nvm.

Please find the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69210383/337011