# Xcode cloud suddenly failing to link node and install dependencies

Tags: node.js, react-native, homebrew, xcode-cloud

I've been trying to figure out why this xcode cloud custom scripts suddenly started failing on me yesterday since I haven't changed anything and it was working before:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

export HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP=TRUE
brew install cocoapods
# have to add node yourself
brew install node@16
# link it to the path
brew link node@16

brew install yarn

# Install dependencies you manage with CocoaPods.
yarn
pod install
# the sed command from RN cant find the file... so we have to run it ourselves
sed -i -e  $'s/ && (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_10_0)//' /Volumes/workspace/repository/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h
```

For some reason it has started failing with the following errors:

```
==> Installing node@16 dependency: brotli

==> Pouring brotli--1.0.9.monterey.bottle.tar.gz

Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully

The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local

Could not symlink include/brotli

/usr/local/include is not writable.

You can try again using:

  brew link brotli
```

Then it keeps giving me same errors that it could not link for a few other dependencies.

When it tries to run `yarn` I get this:

```
yarn requires a Node installation to function. You can install one with:

  brew install node
```

Assuming the node installation didn't work successfully.

Then finally this:

```
[in /Volumes/workspace/repository/ios]

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: cannot load such file -- /Volumes/workspace/repository/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.

 #  from /Volumes/workspace/repository/ios/Podfile:1

 #  -------------------------------------------

 >  require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'

 #  require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

 #  -------------------------------------------

sed: /Volumes/workspace/repository/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h: No such file or directory
```

*EDIT*

Seems like I'm not the only one experiencing this:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/712550

It seems to be an issue with the platform and not by my config apparently.

Comment: Still the issue today

Answer (score 1):

Changing the macOS version (in Workflow environment settings) from "Latest release" to 12.4 could help.

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you

Comment: The fix not working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a workaround by installing node from the .tar.gz from node website:

```
NODE_VER=16
VERSION=$(curl -s https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v$NODE_VER.x/ | sed -nE 's|.*>node-(.*)\.pkg</a>.*|\1|p')
if [[ "$(arch)" == "arm64" ]]
then
  ARCH="arm64"
else
  ARCH="x64"
fi

curl "https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v$NODE_VER.x/node-$VERSION-darwin-$ARCH.tar.gz" -o $HOME/Downloads/node.tar.gz
tar -xf "$HOME/Downloads/node.tar.gz"
NODE_PATH="$PWD/node-$VERSION-darwin-$ARCH/bin"
PATH+=":$NODE_PATH"
export PATH
node -v
npm -v
```

also: If you need node to build a react native app you need to generate `ios/.xcode.env.local` so it exports `$NODE_BINARY`:

```
echo "export NODE_BINARY=$(which node)" > ../.xcode.env.local
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem trying to build a React Native app. I took a similar approach to @343max but instead installed nvm via curl and then used nvm to install node.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

nvm install 16
```

Then I created a symlink to this node installation so that Xcode could find it ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44492197/8698507)).

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin
ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node
```