# React Native iOS: Is there a way to export Node Binary without hardcoding my username?

Tags: node.js, xcode, react-native, nvm

When building my React Native app I got the `Can't find 'node' binary to build React Native bundle` error, and found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492197/react-native-ios-build-cant-find-node) where you go to `Build Phases` -> `Bundle React Native code and images` and add lines like this:

[image]

Where in this example ^^ the node binary was located at `/opt/homebrew/bin/node`, for me it's located at `/Users/<me>/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/node`. I feel like it can't be good practice to a) hard code my username into XCode, and b) to hard code the specific node version.

**What I Want To Know:**

1. Is the effect of adding these lines that it replaces the node version in `react-native-xcode.sh` with my own (16.14.2)?
2. If so, could I just change my local node version to match the one in `react-native-xcode.sh`? I can't find a reference in that file to a particular version, so I don't know which one I'd use in `nvm use <version>`.
3. Is there a different way I could write these lines in `Bundle React Native code and images` that wouldn't hard code the version in this way?

Answer (score 0):

with the latest version of xcode starting from xcode 14.2 you have a `xcode.env` and you can use

```
# This `.xcode.env` file is versioned and is used to source the environment
# used when running script phases inside Xcode.
# To customize your local environment, you can create an `.xcode.env.local`
# file that is not versioned.

# NODE_BINARY variable contains the PATH to the node executable.
#
# Customize the NODE_BINARY variable here.
# For example, to use nvm with brew, add the following line
# . "$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh" --no-use
export NODE_BINARY=$(command -v node)
```